# Can we replace runnable code with coroutine?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, runnable

I am trying to scroll the `ScrollView` until the bottom of a view inside the `ScrollView`.
I found a working solution like this in StackOverflow.

```
scrollView.post {
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myAwesomeTextView.bottom) 
}
```

I want to avoid Runnable and use Coroutine instead. I am wondering how can we replace this code with coroutine?
I tried following way, but didn't work.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myAwesomeTextView.bottom) 
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason for avoiding Runnable?

Comment: I am curious why your coroutine didn't work, though. It looks fine, although it would be more typical to use `lifecycleScope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From performance and code quality perspective, in this particular case there is no advantage of using coroutines instead of `View.post`. `scrollView.post` is very well suited for the use case, since it will queue the operation on the `scrollView`'s message queue, so the operation will execute once the view is attached to the window. which means you don't have to handle the edge cases where view might not have been initialized etc.

Using coroutines here will complicate things and will not add any performance advantage.